# Share animation values with child components - React reanimated 2

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I have a snack [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@francot/reanimated---pass-values-to-sibling) where I want to take the scroll Y value and pass it to an animated view inside a sibling component and have that view animate as I scroll, for this example I just want to animate the height. Smaller when scrolling down, larger when scrolling up (doesn't matter). The snack currently passes it as state which I know is incorrect but I'm not sure how else I would achieve this.

How I can animate the component the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I'm overthinking it. Just use the `useSharedValue` hook and pass the scroll value in there then use it as a prop on the sibling component...

Here is the updated [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@francot/reanimated---pass-values-to-sibling---fixed) if anyone was wondering